# UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find "libadblockplus-jni.so" in Android debug build

Tags: android, android-webview, adblock

I am using AdblockWebView

> https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android

in my Android app. I have three build types: "release", "debug" and "dev", and the Webview was working while I was testing "dev" build type.

However, when I launch "debug" type, which is different from "dev" only with config constants, the app crashes when I open webview activity with no reason at all.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app....debug-W8BipJfr6wKqz06J0zWgrQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app...debug-W8BipJfr6wKqz06J0zWgrQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/app....debug-W8BipJfr6wKqz06J0zWgrQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libadblockplus-jni.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:27)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.AdblockEngine$Builder.createEngines(AdblockEngine.java:265)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.AdblockEngine$Builder.build(AdblockEngine.java:250)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.SingleInstanceEngineProvider.createAdblock(SingleInstanceEngineProvider.java:174)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.SingleInstanceEngineProvider.access$100(SingleInstanceEngineProvider.java:35)
    at org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.SingleInstanceEngineProvider$1.run(SingleInstanceEngineProvider.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I tried deleting "dev" build type, but that does not help. I tried searching the web for hours, but the only thing I found relevant was [this](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6396?cversion=0&cnum_hist=4)

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/Name/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 15
        versionName "1.3.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example debug"
            buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_URL", '"https://api.example.com/"'
        }
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            debuggable true
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example dev"
            buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_URL", '"https://dev.example.com/"'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "example"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BACKEND_URL", '"https://api.example.com/"'
        }
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.0'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:stfalcon-imageviewer:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.9'
    implementation 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.4.4'
    implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.16'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.4.4'
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.16.0'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.3.0'
    // Chrome Tab matching
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    // App indexing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
}

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Updating the library version to 4.0 fixed my issue.

Comment: @MitabShrestha can you post this as answer, so I could accept it? I didn't solve it in the end, and stopped using AdblockWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem with

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:3.0'
```

but degrading  Gradle Plugin Version to `3.4.2` worked but I need to use  Gradle Plugin Version to `4.1` for data binding. After updating to

```
implementation 'org.adblockplus:adblock-android-webview:4.0'
```

it is working now. I have used `gradle plugin version 4.1.1` and `gradle version 6.5` in project structure. I was able to block most of the ads but still 5% ads bypass it.

- Also note: This adblockplus library makes your apk size huge. In my case changed apk size from 11MB to 33 MB. Use bundle while releasing on playstore

Answer (score 1):

It's not generating **libadblockplus-jni.so** in libs folder of the app.

For me it started to happen after updating to Android Gradle 3.5.0. After changing it back to 3.4.2, it worked.

Try to change your Android Gradle Plugin Version to 3.4.2 in Project Structure,
**File > Project Structure > Project**

[Project Structure Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6dO0.png)